# php page automaticly adding doublequotes to my page

Tags: php

I'm having a problem where my page automaticly puts two doublequotes outside php tags (`""`)
This happens as soon as the page contains `<?php` and `?>` and I can't find out why.. Nor should it be my php settings because files in other directories work... except for this files somehow, here are the codes:

index.php

```
<html>
<?php include 'include/head.php' ?>
some data to test
</body>
</html>
```

head.php

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/common.css.php">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/header.css.php">
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">test data</div>
```

and both of the CSS files are empty, I work with `.css.php` because I have been told that this could greatly improve loading speeds.. This all together gives me the following code in chrome, and Internet explorer:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
"
"
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/common.css.php">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/header.css.php">
<div id="test">test data</div>
"
somedatatotest"
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

EDIT: Real browser source:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/common.css.php">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/header.css.php">
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">test</div>
some data to test
```

Comment: Maybe because you have no `<body>` tag? and no `<html>` too?

Comment: I tried using them, same result.

Comment: This cannot be the real source code. Where do the `html` and `body` tags come from? Please show the real source code or clearly state what type of code you do show.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware added a screenshot of the source, viewed from Chrome

Comment: @KIKOSoftware browser added them automatically

Comment: To view the real source code in Chrome, right click anywhere in the page and select 'View Page Source'. You're looking at the constructed DOM elements.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware added to original post.

Comment: See, exactly what you would expect. Where does the `body` tag come from? I don't see it in your PHP files.

Comment: Dude, that is not my question or whatsoever, neither is it a problem, all I'm asking is how I get rid of the doublequotes.

Comment: Sorry, I'll shut up.

Comment: Do you get the double quotes even if you comment out the `.css.php` styling files?

Comment: Yup even then @vlzvl

Comment: Can you try to switch off all extension in Chrome? It's worth a try, since there seems nothing wrong with the source code. It doesn't explain why the same thing happens in IE. I've saved your source code in a HTML file and loaded it in Chrome. No double quotes.

Comment: Hello @KIKOSoftware, I have just disabled all my Plugins, unfortunately it still gives the same result. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the problem, It seems that my Notepad++ settings were wrong, it would create files with the UTF-8 coding and ANSI enabled, but since I set my settings to UTF-8 (WITHOUT BOM) and ANSI coding ignored everything seems to be workign fine again.

Comment: Ah, who would have guessed that? Thank you for letting us know.

Comment: Remember @KIKOSoftware, you were told not to talk. :P

Comment: I did not tell him to stop talking @DarkRanger, all I told was that he was talking about things that didn't have anything to do with my problem, and I had / have proof of that

Comment: @Azrael: Try to use UTF-8 without BOM. If you want to use UTF-8 everywhere (as you should) you'd better use it... or your accented characters will be a mess.

Comment: I do @STTLCU but I did not include that in the awnser as I wasn't sure if it was also called BOM in english haha

Comment: BOM is english. Byte Order Mark ;) I'd update your answer, so we can have more utf8 pages and less ansi pages :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `index.php` file to this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php include 'include/head.php' ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test">test data</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And your `head.php` file to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/common.css.php">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/header.css.php">
```

No questions, just do this. Promise it will solve your problem.

EDIT: Also, why is it `common.css.php` and not just `common.css`?

EDIT 2: Okay, do this then. You've got to atleast try some of the suggestions, otherwise no one will want to help you.

```
//index.php
<html>
    <?php include 'include/head.php' ?>
        <div id="test">test data</div>
    </body>
</html>

//head.php
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/common.css.php">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/header.css.php">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">some head test data</div>
```

Comment: Hello DarkRanger, Thanks for your awnser, however this won't fix my problem because my head.php is also going to include other tags like some `<div>`s etcetera.

Comment: Hello @DarkRanger, your code got rid of the second pair of doublequotes.. which is already a huge step further than I got.. and I'm using `.css.php` because I have been told this improves loading speeds.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing a well formed HTML document to your browser, and the rendering engine is trying its best to show what it has got.

Since your HTML isn't well formed, you can't expect a predictable output. Fix your source, and the problem will be solved

Comment: Updated my code, it got all the tags like `<head>`,`<body>` etcetera, still the same.